# I have an application to run with spring boot. I need to use hibernate with it. I get this exception

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an application to run with spring boot. I need to use hibernate with it. I get this exception. I'm not sure about the configuration files I should have. Since I have searched so much and new to spring: I have pom.xml, and  I don't know whether I should have web.xml or not. I need to get it work as soon as possible. this is my exception thrown:

---

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file 
        [C:\Users\Mehrnaz\JEEKeplerWorkspace\rest-stack\target\classes\com\jl\crm\contoller\UserController.class]: 
        Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[com.jl.crm.services.CrmService]: : Error creating bean with name 'jpaCrmService' defined in file 
        [C:\Users\Mehrnaz\JEEKeplerWorkspace\rest-stack\target\classes\com\jl\crm\services\JpaCrmService.class]: 
        Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[com.jl.crm.repository.CustomerRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type 
[com.jl.crm.repository.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: 
        expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
        Dependency annotations: {}; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
        No qualifying bean of type [com.jl.crm.repository.CustomerRepository] 
        found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
        Dependency annotations: {}; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'jpaCrmService' defined in file 
        [C:\Users\Mehrnaz\JEEKeplerWorkspace\rest-stack\target\classes\com\jl\crm\services\JpaCrmService.class]: 
        Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[com.jl.crm.repository.CustomerRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type 
[com.jl.crm.repository.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: 
        expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

=======

my pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <artifactId>rest-stack</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>demo</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
 
 
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
          

        </dependency>
     
   <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
              <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
       <!-- MySQL -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 </dependency> 
  <!--  other project -->
     <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
               <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
             <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
  
 
 </dependencies>
 
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 

</project>
```

my web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <context-param>
     <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
     <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
     </param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>com.jl.crm.services.ServiceConfiguration</param-value>
 </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
       
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have log4j.properties:

```html
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout
```

and Application.properties:

```html
#
## Database configuration
#
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/spring
spring.datasource.username= spring
spring.datasource.password= spring
spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

this is service.configuration class, that I think may have problem:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    public static final String CRM_NAME = "crm";
    /**
     * The root directory to which all uploads for the application are uploaded.
     */
    public static final File CRM_STORAGE_DIRECTORY = new File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), CRM_NAME);
    /**
     * Things are first uploaded by the application server to this directory. it's a sort
     * of staging directory
     */
    public static final File CRM_STORAGE_UPLOADS_DIRECTORY = new File(CRM_STORAGE_DIRECTORY, "uploads");
    /**
     * When a profile photo is uploaded, the resultant, completely uploaded image is
     * stored in this directory
     */
    public static final File CRM_STORAGE_PROFILES_DIRECTORY = new File(CRM_STORAGE_DIRECTORY, "profiles");

    @PostConstruct
    protected void setupStorage() throws Throwable {
        File[] files = {CRM_STORAGE_DIRECTORY, CRM_STORAGE_UPLOADS_DIRECTORY, CRM_STORAGE_PROFILES_DIRECTORY};
        for (File f : files) {
            if (!f.exists() && !f.mkdirs()) {
                String msg = String.format("you must create the profile photos directory ('%s') " +
                        "and make it accessible to this process. Unable to do so from this process.", f.getAbsolutePath());
                throw new RuntimeException(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(  JpaVendorAdapter adapter, DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setPackagesToScan(User.class.getPackage().getName());
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager( EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile({"default", "test"})
    static class DefaultDataSourceConfiguration {

        private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        @PostConstruct
        protected void setupTestProfileImages() throws Exception {
            long userId = 5;
            File profilePhotoForUser5 = new File(ServiceConfiguration.CRM_STORAGE_PROFILES_DIRECTORY, Long.toString(userId));
            if (!profilePhotoForUser5.exists()) {
                // copy the profile photo back
                String pathForProfilePhoto = "/sample-photos/spring-dog-2.png";
                ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(pathForProfilePhoto);
                Assert.isTrue(classPathResource.exists(), "the resource " + pathForProfilePhoto + " does not exist");
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(profilePhotoForUser5);
                InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
                try {
                    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
                }
                log.debug("setup photo " + profilePhotoForUser5.getAbsolutePath() + " for the sample user #" + Long.toString(userId) + "'s profile photo.");
            }
            if (!profilePhotoForUser5.exists()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("couldn't setup profile photos at " + profilePhotoForUser5.getAbsolutePath() + ".");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No qualifying bean of type [com.jl.crm.repository.CustomerRepository] found

Answer (score 0):

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration(basePackages = {"<Specify your base package here>"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ServiceConfiguration {
---
}
```

you missed base package name for the `componentscan` annotation.

Comment: I used:@ComponentScan("com.jl.crm") as my base package. didn't work.

Comment: make sense, And make sure all your  @ Repository, @ Service,  @ Controller annotated classes should fall under the same package.

Comment: It appears you application not comply with Spring boot, read this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot

Comment: yes , I had to migrate to "Spring Boot" without extra setting . Now I I understand that the problem with connection to database, could solve it by adding annotations to entities classes. Hope it helps others.